# Vue.js, Use plugin methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am building a SPA with Vue for the first time. I am going to re-use a couple of functions but can't seem to make it work. I get the error `"this.ExperienceToLevel is not a function"`.

At the same time, I'm not even sure creating a plugin is the best way to achieve what I am trying to. Which is, making some functions global "the Vue way". I **don't** want to assign it to *window* like `window.UserLevel = new UserLevel()`.

UserLevel.js

```
/*
Create Levels array
 */
let Levels = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    let xp = Math.floor(Math.pow(i, 1.3) * 100);
    Levels.push(xp);
}

/*
Create UserLevel Plugin
 */
const UserLevel = {
    install(Vue, options) {
        Vue.ExperienceToLevel = function (xp) {
            for (const [level, levelXP] of Object.entries(options.levels)) {
                if (levelXP > xp) {
                    return level-1;
                }
            }
        }

        Vue.LevelToExperience = function (level) {
            return options.levels[level];
        }

        Vue.ExperiencePercent = function (level) {
            return ((this.xp - this.LevelToExperience(this.level)) / (this.LevelToExperience(this.level + 1) - this.LevelToExperience(this.level))) * 100;
        }
    }
};

export {
    Levels,
    UserLevel
};
```

I try to import the plugin into a component like this:

```
import { UserLevel, Levels } from './../../UserLevel';
Vue.use(UserLevel, { levels: Levels });
```

And use the global methods like so: `this.ExperienceToLevel(this.xp)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Vue documentation on Plugins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html), you have two options:

Declare those methods inside a `mixin`:

```
const UserLevel = {
    install(Vue, options) {
        Vue.mixin({
            methods: {
                ExperienceToLevel(xp) { ... },
                LevelToExperience(level) { ... },
                ExperiencePercent(level) { ... },
            }
        })
    }
};
```

Or bind them to `Vue.prototype`:

```
Vue.prototype.$ExperienceToLevel = function (xp) { ... }
Vue.prototype.$LevelToExperience = function (level) { ... }
Vue.prototype.$ExperiencePercent = function (level) { ... }
```

I would go with the former.

Comment: I vote for the former as well. I just noticed that calling a prototype method from a template loses the `this` object.